# Retrieve customer password in magento from database

Tags: database, django, zend-framework, magento, passwords

I have migrated my project site from magento to django, it is a site with millions of users. I have successfully imported all the data from the site but the main problem I am having, is to migrate customer database especially with password, because obviously I can't give new passwords to each customer on django site because it will be so time consuming. And for the customers to reset the password, will be very irritating and many customers will be lost from the site.

Please give me some ideas how can I retrieve customer password in magento from database?

Answer (score 3):

You can not restore passwords. Magento uses hashes with salt for storing passwords (md5 and sha1 according to the edition).

Only things you can do - reset passwords or implement in your site the same function for checking passwords as it's done in magento.

Answer (score 1):

At a glance it looks like django stores it's passwords using `md5${salt}${hashed_password}` and they prepend the salt. This being the case you should be able to take the Magento passwords and reformat the string so that it passes django password checks.

```
$hashArr = explode(':', $hash);
$newPasswordString = 'md5$'.$hashArr[1].'$'.$hashArr[0];
```

The viability / accuracy of this answer will depend on whether you are using Community / Professional or Enterprise. The code is based on the Community code as I can share this more freely, depending on the implementation the same may or may not be possible with Enterprise, you'd need to check `Mage_Core_Model_Encryption:validateHash`.

Comment: Enterprise uses a one-way hash in the same way CE will and the format of the data in the database is the same, but it uses a salted sha256 (older EE versions used sha1) hash instead of md5 for better security. If you do happen to have an md5 hash in the database, Enterprise will update the hash it keeps in the db the next time the user logs in.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep old and weak hashes from legacy systems, you are endangering your users.

If some attacker (or some evil admin) gets access to the hashes and user data, he can easily crack them (see e.g. http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat-plus/ ) and use them globally against any service your users are using (of course users are advised to not reuse passwords, have strong passwords, etc., but many will not know or ignore this).

Weak hashes are about anything *except* bcrypt, pbkdf2, shaXXX_crypt. Even something like randomly salted sha256 has to be considered as weak.

So, a sane procedure could be:

1. Do NOT just support weak hashes directly
2. Import the weak hashes, but hash them again using strong algo: strong(weak(cleartext))
3. At login time, upgrade the double-hashed stuff to just strong(cleartext)
4. Run the system in this mode for a while, your frequent users will have strong(cleartext) hashes at some time.
5. To get rid of the inner weak() hash, invalidate all such hashes (this will only affect your infrequent users), send users a password-reset link and some contact info for cases of trouble. In the E-Mail you can point out that you care very much about security and that the reset is necessary to improve it. If the infrequent user is still interested in your service, he will just reset his password. If he is not interested any more, he will ignore the email. In any case, you won't have a double-hashed pw in your password storage any more, but just an invalid one.
6. Disable support for the inner weak() hash, for double-hashing in the site configuration.
7. Deprecate support for the inner hash / double hashing in the software.
8. Later, remove support for the inner hash / double hashing in the software, to simplify it.

Note: if the legacy system had security breaches, taking the old hashes is no option as you have to consider the passwords to be exposed.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a guide in you quest:

[How to decrypt magento enterprise edition password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643618/how-to-decrypt-magento-enterprise-edition-password)

Comment: magento does not use encryption for customer's password. Only one-way hashing (and this is written under your link)

Comment: Magento stores passwords as one way hashes, no decryption possible. Break out the rainbow tables and start brute forcing.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Cags works for me.  I'm moving from Magento community edition 1.7 to Django-Oscar.

I only have a few hundred users to move, but resetting their passwords wasn't an option.

For convenience...

The python version of his code:

```
hash = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xx  # The hash from Magento DB table customer_entity_varchar
splithash = hash.split(':')
djangopass = 'md5$' + splithash[1] + '$' + splithash[0]
```