# How to get the user's password and insert it into a new bank

Tags: php, magento

I have the hash passwords of my magento clients, I am migrating to a new bank all the data of the old bank, I would like to know how to enter the passwords in the users.

I use this to re-create the users on the new site, I would use their passwords, how can I put them there?

**Code**

```
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app(0);

$link = mysqli_connect('databaseip', 'login', 'password', 'database');
$link->set_charset("utf8");
$query = "SELECT * from customers";
$select = mysqli_query($link, $query);
foreach($select as $key => $selects) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select)) {
        $teste = array(
            $clientes_id = $row['clientes_id'],
            $nome = $row['nome'],
            $sobrenome = $row['sobrenome'],
            $site = $row['site'],
            $loja = $row['loja'],
            $grupo = $row['grupo'],
            $email = $row['email'],
            $criadoem = $row['criadoem']
        );

        $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
        $customer->setId($clientes_id)->setFirstname($nome)->setLastname($sobrenome)->setWebsiteId($site)->setStoreId($loja)->setGroupId($grupo)->setEmail($email)->setCreatedAt($criadoem)->setPassword('');


        $customer->save();
    }
}
```

And I use this code to get the passwords, what should I do to insert them correctly in the users?

**Code**

```
$customer_email = 'test@test.com';
$customer_password = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()
->getWebsite()->getId())->loadByEmail($customer_email)->getPasswordHash()."\n";

print_r(array("Passwrd_Hash"=>$customer_password));
```

**What I get**

```
[Passwrd_Hash] => 6ca46cdc372243d3e768c306c07edcc0:e4OKoYvFzKQVGgZRQJIFp9ntAMMQCmYf
```

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. 
It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**.
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. 
You may be asked to amend this code in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: My codes are indented, however whenever I add a code here the staff removes all the indentation and leaves it "stuck". I do not know why it's to gain more reputation or something, but the code is indented ^^

Comment: Use 3-4 spaces instead of tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Magento stores only hash of the customer passwords. Storing the passwords in plain text is not secure. If you want to set the password to customer model and you don't know plain password, but you know only hash then you can use method **setPasswordHash**.

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($id);
$customer->setPasswordHash('...');
$customer->save();
```

However, don't forget that Magento uses **md5** to create the hash. If you stored the passwords that are hashed by another way then your users would not be able to login by their passwords.

If you migrate the passwords from another Magento then I guess there will no problem.

Comment: I'm migrating from one magento to another, the magento I was using was Enterprise 1.4 and what I'm using is community 1.9, when I give a `getPasswordHash` I get two concatenated values, I set the integer value or just one of values?

Comment: I'm sorry I dont know EE versions. I worked only with CE versions. There may be different way to storing the passwords and so they may not be interchangeable see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643618/how-to-decrypt-magento-enterprise-edition-password